# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'W' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, linux

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095401/python-2-7-classes/17095610#17095610). I was advised to make a separate python library and then import it.

After reading a bit more on `Stackoverflow`, I realized that the best way is to [write methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script) and I've taken up that path.

```
def USB(port):
        activateme = serial.Serial(port,115200)
        #print "starting to monitor"
        for line in activateme:
                #print line
                return line

def USBprocess(line):
        if line.startswith( '#d'):
                fields = line.split(',')
                if len(fields) > 5:
                        W = fields[1]
                        V = fields[2]
                        A = fields[3]
                print "monitoring"
        return W,V,A

op = USB(port)
w,v,a = USBprocess(op)
```

and I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'W' referenced before assignment
```

what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error will be thrown when the if condition is false because then there will be no variable `W` to return

Comment: Clearly, the line did not strat with `#d`.. What do you think should happen in that was the case?

Comment: BTW, you can do `W, V, A = fields[1:4]`, or simply `return fields[1:4]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should provide values for `W, V, A` at the start of the function, in case the first `if` condition is not `True`. Something like this, perhaps (change for default values appropriate for your problem):

```
def USBprocess(line):
    W, V, A = '0', '0', '0'
    if line.startswith('#d'):
        # etc.
```

Comment: for example `W = A = V = None`

Answer (score 0):

In case this expression is not true:

```
 line.startswith( '#d')
```

variables `W`, `V` and `A` will not be initialized in your `USBprocess` function, so `return` will fail.

Fix it by initializing all local variables before the `if` statement.